# Get a high speed connection without roaming charges instantly

Tags: adverbs, word-order, construction

I saw this message on an advert:

> Get a high speed connection without
>   roaming charges instantly.

I am pretty sure that a better way to say it is:

> Instantly get a high speed connection
>   without roaming charges.

If I am right about the first construction being wrong/poor, is there a name for the *abusage*? I run across such constructions fairly regularly.

Comment: Here's another one: Glad to see your email finally. (instead of _finally see_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions are grammatically correct.  Your version (with the adverb at the front) would probably be more common in most writing or speech — it is slightly unusual for an adverb to get separated from its verb phrase by another adverbial phrase like this.  In this case it seems OK (at least to my ear); but I’d agree that in some cases the separated version can really be quite horrible, to the point of being ungrammatical; compare:

> Sally ate the cake quickly with great pleasure.

> ?Sally ate the cake with great pleasure quickly.

However, in advertising (like in headline-writing), writers are trying to fulfil a lot of other demands in a very small space, so somewhat unusual phrasings often occur.  In this case, putting “Get a high-speed roaming connection” first makes the subject of the ad more immediately clear, and putting “instantly” last gives the phrase a good punchy ending.  I’d guess these are the sorts of things the writer had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the "instantly" applies to how fast you can get a high speed connection.

It would rather apply to how fast you start having increasing charges *as soon as* you get said high speed connection.
In that sense, the construction is adequate.

Comment: Knowing phone companies, that may well be the case — but I’m sure that the meaning the writers intended was the OP’s interpretation, “Get a high-speed connection […] instantly”.

Comment: @PLL: I really don't think so. I rather see that as a direct reference to the infamous "iphone bill" ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdULhkh6yeA )

Comment: It's what read as well. The sentence is poorly phrased. Nontheless lot of people will not read excetly the way what you and I do.

Comment: LOL... The intention of the advertisement got changed.

Comment: +1 for translating marketing-speak into plausible reality.